# RxJs how to map an aray of objects to array of string?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am beginner in RxJs, please advice me how to transform a list of objects in a list of its names, like here:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

var names = this.http.get<Project[]>('/api/projects').pipe(map(p=> p.name));
```

it says `name` does not exist on the `Project[]`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a valid error since `p` in your code is an array. To achieve what you want use `map` method:

```
this.http.get<Project[]>('/api/projects').pipe(
  map(projects => projects.map(project => project.name))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

map oprator is not iterating through your Projects array. It stands between observable stream value and returns what you mutate or want with data . So you need to perform a js map inside Map oprator to mutate data to what you want

```
 var names = this.http.get<Project[]> 
  ('/api/projects').pipe(map(projects=> projects.map(p=> // whatever you wana do)))
```